# Member initialisation in c#

Tags: c#

I have two classes, `class A` and `class B`.

```
public class A
{ 
    public int someNumber;

    public A(int a)
    {
        someNumber = a; 
    }
}
```

Now `class B` has a field that is an object of `class A`. In C++ it is possible to do this:

```
public class B
{
    public A foo;

    public B(int a) : foo(a) { }
}
```

But this doesnt work in C#. So how can one solve this problem in C# without using a default constructor in `class A`. To be more precise, how is it possible to write a constructor for `class B` that takes as parameter the `someNumber` value of `foo`?

Comment: This isn't really about C++.  Could you remove the C++ tag please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public class B 
{

    public A thing;

    public B(int a)
    {
        thing = new A(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to put `thing` instead of `A` for the assignment.

Comment: @MaxWeinzierl you are bloody correct ! My bad. Thanks

Comment: @Christos oh, ok, thanks. I assumed this would not work because I thought that a constructor always initialized all the class members before the body of the constructor is executed. Which then leads to an error if there is no default constructor for a certain member.

Comment: @Morten actually class members _are_ initialized before the constructor body - to 0 for value types and to `null` for reference types.